# How to use two URL mappings

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to migrate my application to Spring Boot Jar Deployment. It currently uses Spring 4 without Boot.

I have a REST-API listening at `/api/*` and a Javascript-Frontend at `src/main/webapp` which can be accessed at `/*`.

Now i don't find a way doing the same in Boot.

I managed to get my api listening at `/api/*` by changing the `server.context-path` property but I didn't manage to register a second servlet to serve my js-frontend at `/*`. I know that `src/main/webapp`is not supported by a jar deployment and i also know that Spring Boot serves static files from `src/resources/public` and `src/resources/static`. But in my case these folder then also points to `/api/*` because of the `server.context-path` change.

I tried is to register another servlet as a bean. This destroyed my api-endpoint.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

First option - copy everything from `src/main/webapp` into `src/resources/static`. This is where Spring Boot looks for that static content.

Second option, keep using `src/main/webapp`, but configure your build to copy the static resources into `target/classes/static`. I provided the Maven config for this on a previous answer: [Refreshing static content with Spring MVC and Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24762657/refreshing-static-content-with-spring-mvc-and-boot/24764196#24764196)

Note that if you go with the first option, if you wish to modify content and have it automatically reloaded without running a build, you will need to run your application inside your IDE. Going with the second option gives you the usual Tomcat reloading of static content if you're executing your jar, but could lead to some confusion. Personally, I go with the second option most of the time, as I like to run the application on the command line and edit my HTML and JavaScript with Chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: I know this solution, but the problem is that i mapped the default servlet to `/api/*`. So also everything under `src/resources/static`will be mapped to `/api/*`. But i want it to be mapped to `/*`.

Comment: If you want something to map to `/*`, then you need to remove your servlet context mapping to `/api/*` and everything should work. Your REST controllers should define their own mappings to `/api/whatever`.

Comment: but because of that i tried to register a second servlet. it would also be okay if it starts at `/web/*`. but prefixing every controller with `api` doesn't sound very clean.

Comment: If you want a single application to respond to `/*`, then its root needs to be `/`, which means that the `@RequestMapping` at the top of each REST controller can be `/api/something`, and everything works out of the Spring Boot box. So far I find that having the actual mapping to my REST controllers in their mapping annotations makes the code easier to follow.

Comment: I want my REST-API to respond at `/api/* `and my static HTML to respond at `/*` or `/web/*`. And i don't want to prefix all my `@RequestMapping`s with `/api`.

Comment: In that case it would probably be worth re-writing your question to make clear that's what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @DavidSchilling If all your API endpoints are within a single controller you can add a class-level `@RequestMapping("/api/")` that will be prefixed to all method-level `@RequestMapping`s.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple mappings, you will have to add one per mapping and map that in controller like below.

```
 @Controller
 @RequestMapping(value = { "${url.mapping}","${url.mapping.two}" })
 public class CustomerController{
```