# Dynamic change on html files in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-mvc, gradle, spring-boot

I have a SpringBoot application with web enabled, so i have my html pages files on 
/src/main/resources/static.

But i have to **restart** the application everytime in order to see the changes i make on any file on that path and that's a waste of time, does anybody knows a "fix" to this problem?

Thanks..!

Comment: For IDE i'm using MyEclipse

Comment: If you are using the default Thymeleaf templating engine, turn off template caching by adding `spring.thymeleaf.cache=false` to `application.properties` (by default template caching is on). If using another templating engine, set the corresponding property to `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which IDE are you using? In IntelliJ there's an option to "update resources" without needing an app server restart.
Look at this [SO questions for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24762657/refreshing-static-content-with-spring-mvc-and-boot)

Comment: I'm using MyEclipse

Comment: I will test  it  tomorrow, Michele, i had other assigment urgently.. thanks  and tomorrow i tell  u  :D