# Spring-boot, thymeleaf load uploaded image without application server restart

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, image-upload

My question is, what is the best practice to store images with spring boot and thymeleaf, if I want to load the image without the restart of the application. At the moment I'm able to upload the image so I see it in the uploaded folder and in the database I've stored It's name, But then when I refresh the page the Image is not loaded. I'm retrieving the image standard way in thymeleaf `<img th:src="@{'../images/'+${product.image}}"`. The path is correct because after restart of the server the image is loaded.I guess there is a problem with static folder that It's included in jar and couldn't be changed. But what is the best practice to solve this kind of problem in spring boot. Thanks

Comment: Your post looks not only too clumsy but not clear; you should consider editing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `static` directory is loaded at startup. So any changes files added after the `ApplicationContext` is finished. You probably would be interested in this post: [Refreshing static content with Spring MVC and Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24762657/refreshing-static-content-with-spring-mvc-and-boot) I would look past Dave Syer's post as he is talking about the IDE only, but the answer below that by Steve should help you.