# How to update resources at runtime in spring boot-angular project using IntelliJ IDE

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, intellij-idea, hotswap

I am new to Spring boot and angular so lease bear with me if something is not clear in the question or I am asking something trivial. I downloaded a sample project for learning purposes and I am able to deploy the application

Project structure
I have a REST spring boot application with an empty `webapp` directory

Angular project is a separate module which is built by running `ng build` in the parent folder and when the project is built the angular assets are moved to `webapp` folder of the spring project

Then running the `mvn clean install` I generate the war file for the application and deploy it using simple `Run Application.java`

Now the problem with the project is every time I make a change in the Angular project I have to re-deploy the whole application :(

I was wondering if there is a way to hotswap resources i.e. webapp files in the deployed war when I make changes to the UI using IntelliJ IDE

I have visited the following questions on this topic and nothing has helped so far.

[StackOverflow Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24762657/refreshing-static-content-with-spring-mvc-and-boot)

[JetBrains support ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-141638)

[Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-hotswapping.html)

Comment: If you build the project using Maven, you will not be able to hot deploy using IntelliJ IDEA. In case the artifact is built by IntelliJ IDEA (exploded), update will work per https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/updating-applications-on-application-servers.html.

Comment: I deploy my application using mvn spring-boot:run so I do not have that option of reloading the frame. I tried using Tomcat just to test if it works but it does not :(