# Webpack bundle.js changes not showing in a Spring application without restarting the server?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, webpack

I followed this tutorial for creating a Spring-boot+ ReactJs app: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/

The application starts fine with `./mvnw spring-boot: run`, and I have  an NPM script `"watch": "webpack --watch -d"` that runs the following configuration

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main/js/app.js',
    devtool: 'sourcemaps',
    cache: true,
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: './src/main/resources/static/built/bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: path.join(__dirname, '.'),
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
                    }
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

`app.js` gets compiled into `bundle.js` as expected but if I don't restart the server with `./mvnw spring-boot:run` when I refresh the page I can't see the changes.

I might be missing something, is maybe spring-boot not using my `bundle.js` file but a copy of some sort?

Answer (score 0):

I can guess embedded tomcat does not hot reload static files. You can try some of these [Refreshing static content with Spring MVC and Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24762657/refreshing-static-content-with-spring-mvc-and-boot)

But will also share my solution, which is using webpack-dev-server to hot reload and web development in general.

```
const path = require('path');
...
devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
    publicPath: '/build',
    port: 8000,
    proxy: {
        "**": "http://localhost:8080"
    }
},
```

and then run `webpack-dev-server` command to run it. It compiles you app on the fly and your changes are reflected immediately, definitely give it a try.

Comment: I tried with `webpack-dev-server`, it compiles , but still doesn't reflect the changes.

I also tried with spring's hot reload that requires an additional dependency called `spring-boot-devtools`, which supposedly should do exactly what I want, but it's still not working. 

I'll let you know if I find a working solution. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I got the same question and solve it today.

The key is to run `npm run watch` and `mvn spring-boot:run` at the same time.

make sure you have

```
    "scripts": {
        "watch": "webpack --watch -d --output .//classes/static/built/bundle.js"
    }
```

in your `package.json` and

```
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
         <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

in your `pom.xml`