# Why is spring devtools not working when I change my static files and reload the page?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, devtools

I am using a dependency as:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

The devtools work fine when I make changes to my `.java` files but doesn't work when I make changes in my static files(.html files). Also, the change is not seen when I reload the page. I have to restart the application to see the changes. And it is quite a time consuming to restart the app every time I make a few small changes.

Answer (score 3):

In spring-boot-maven-plugin in pom.xml add the following configuration:

```
<configuration>
    <addResources>true</addResources>
</configuration>
```

The above will work if you starting the app from the command line. However, please see this post for more details on this: [Refreshing static content with Spring MVC and Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24762657/refreshing-static-content-with-spring-mvc-and-boot)

Comment: But this didn't work for me. I am starting the app from an IDE(eclipse). The same devtool is working in a different project but not in this one.

Comment: Follow the link provided. You'll find many solutions. This is a duplicate question by the way.

Answer (score 2):

With Spring Boot 3.1.2, set the following properties in `application-dev.properties`:

```
spring.web.resources.static-locations=file:src/main/resources/static/
spring.devtools.restart.additional-paths=file:src/main/resources/static/
```

I added these configurations in a dev profile because in production static content will be served from the classpath. Remember to activate the correct profile.

What it does:

- Devtools will restart the service whenever there are changes in the static directory and trigger a live reload. It pairs great with live-reload browser extensions.
- Static resources are served from the file system instead of the classpath. It allows serving up-to-date static files without needing to rebuild the project. That way you do not the need to configure your IDE to rebuild on every save which may be a little slow, depending on the project.

I set this up for a web project built using Vite, (`vite build --watch`) and dumping all output in `src/main/resources/static/` Spring Boot Devtools picks up the changes almost immediately.

This answer is the same that I wrote here https://stackoverflow.com/a/76997426/8474661

Comment: why didn't you vote to close as a duplicate?