# Is it possible to edit in-place the static HTML/CSS/JS files in a Spring Boot app?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have a simple Spring Boot app which is built using Maven.

It inherits from the `spring-boot-starter-parent` parent project.

It generates a JAR, with

```
$ mvn clean package
```

And during development, I run it locally, with

```
$ java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=local ./target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I have a number of static HTML CSS and JavaScript files under `src/main/resources/static`.

Each small change to them requires a new build and run cycle.

Is there are way to run the application from the file system rather than the JAR? (As you can with an expanded WAR in, say, Tomcat). And is there a way to edit-in-place any static files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Refreshing static content with Spring MVC and Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24762657/refreshing-static-content-with-spring-mvc-and-boot)

Comment: In particular the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39334398/133203) seems more useful than the chosen one.