# Using Maven to deploy release build to Artifactory results in 403 Forbidden but works for snapshots

Tags: java, maven, artifactory, maven-deploy-plugin

I'm having an issue deploying my Spring Boot JARs to the company's internal `libs-release-local` repository.  When I run the `mvn deploy:deploy-file` command with the appropriate arguments, it deploys successfully from my workstation:

```
mvn package deploy:deploy-file -Durl=https://artifactory.domain.com/artifactory/libs-release-local -Dfile=target/my-app-3.0.0.jar -DpomFile=pom.xml -DrepositoryId=central
```

The above `repositoryId` is defined in my home directory's `settings.xml`.

When I run the same command in GitLab CI, I get the following:

```
[INFO] Uploading to central: https://artifactory.domain.com/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/company/ui/my-app/3.0.0/my-app-3.0.0.jar
[WARNING] Failed to upload checksum com/company/ui/my-app/3.0.0/my-app-3.0.0.jar.md5: Authorization failed for https://artifactory.domain.com/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/company/ui/my-app/3.0.0/my-app-3.0.0.jar.md5 403 Forbidden
org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization.AuthorizationException: Authorization failed for https://artifactory.domain.com/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/company/ui/my-app/3.0.0/my-app-3.0.0.jar.md5 403 Forbidden
```

Both myself and our service account are configured with the same permissions in the `User Management` section of Artifactory.  Even though I see `403 Forbidden` above, the `jar` file still uploads to Artifactory successfully, however the `.jar.md5` and `.pom` files fail with `403 Forbidden`.  I don't see these errors when running within IntelliJ.

Additionally, deploying a `SNAPSHOT` jar to our snapshot repository completes successfully.

**settings.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd"
          xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <localRepository>/root/.m2/repository</localRepository>
    <interactiveMode>false</interactiveMode>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <username>${env.MAVEN_REPO_USER}</username>
            <password>${env.MAVEN_REPO_PASS}</password>
            <id>central</id>
        </server>
        <server>
            <username>${env.MAVEN_REPO_USER}</username>
            <password>${env.MAVEN_REPO_PASS}</password>
            <id>central-snapshots</id>
        </server>
    </servers>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <name>libs-release</name>
                    <url>https://artifactory.company.com/artifactory/libs-release</url>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <snapshots/>
                    <id>central-snapshots</id>
                    <name>libs-snapshot</name>
                    <url>https://artifactory.company.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <name>libs-release</name>
                    <url>https://artifactory.company.com/artifactory/libs-release</url>
                </pluginRepository>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <snapshots/>
                    <id>central-snapshots</id>
                    <name>libs-snapshot</name>
                    <url>https://artifactory.company.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
                </pluginRepository>                
            </pluginRepositories>            
            <properties>
                <altSnapshotDeploymentRepository>
                    central-snapshots::default::https://artifactory.company.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/
                </altSnapshotDeploymentRepository>
                <altReleaseDeploymentRepository>
                    central::default::https://artifactory.company.com/artifactory/libs-release-local/
                </altReleaseDeploymentRepository>
            </properties>
            <id>artifactory</id>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.company.ui</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <argLine/>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <groovy.version>3.0.12</groovy.version>
        <spock.version>2.1-groovy-3.0</spock.version>
        <checkmarx.version>8.90.2</checkmarx.version>
        <jacoco.version>0.8.7</jacoco.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.okta.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>okta-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.rabbitmq</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-rabbitmq</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.pivotal.cfenv</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-cfenv-boot</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${spock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockwebserver</artifactId>
            <version>4.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>4.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2021.0.3</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358403/spring-boot-project-with-static-content-generates-404-when-running-jar -->
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>./client/dist</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.*</include>
                </includes>
                <targetPath>static</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <targetBytecode>11</targetBytecode>
                    <sources>
                        <source>
                            <directory>src/main/groovy</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                            </includes>
                        </source>
                        <source>
                            <directory>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/openapi/src/gen/java/main</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                            </includes>
                        </source>
                    </sources>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>addSources</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>addTestSources</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <!-- By default only files ending in 'Test' will be included, so also include support for Spock style naming convention -->
                        <!-- Oddly enough for Groovy files, *Spec.groovy does not work, but *Spec.java does -->
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                        <include>**/*Spec.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm config set strict-ssl false</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>npm</executable>
                            <workingDirectory>./client</workingDirectory>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>config</argument>
                                <argument>set</argument>
                                <argument>strict-ssl</argument>
                                <argument>false</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>npm</executable>
                            <workingDirectory>./client</workingDirectory>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>install</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>npm run build</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>npm</executable>
                            <workingDirectory>./client</workingDirectory>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>run</argument>
                                <argument>build</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>npm run coverage</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
                            <executable>npm</executable>
                            <workingDirectory>./client</workingDirectory>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>run</argument>
                                <argument>coverage</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: It appears to have occurred due to the conflict either with the existing checksum values [or] the algorithm being enforced by default. Are there any additional errors returned from Artifactory around this timeframe? Especially with the tag "Caused by ..."?

Comment: @Yuvarajan What I don't understand is why I don't see those files getting sent from my local workstation, but see them in my pipeline.  I don't own the pipeline configuration and the team that supports it isn't sure what is going on either :(

Comment: I ended up just going with the standard `mvn clean deploy` instead of trying to deploy a file directly to the repository.  For some reason, that command works and `deploy:deploy-file` does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the standard `mvn deploy` command instead of `deploy-file`.  I'm not sure why, but `deploy-file` would return `HTTP 403 Forbidden` whereas `deploy` publishes the package successfully.